# Solution existence for two-dimensional parabolic PDEs

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, parabolic-pde

I am looking for a solution $(f,g) \in C^{1,2}([0;T]\times\mathbb R;\mathbb R^2)$ to the following PDE system
$$
f_t(t,x) + a_1(t,x) f_x(t,x) + a_2(t,x) f_{xx}(t,x) - b_1 f(t,x)^2 + c(t) g(t,x) - d(t,x) = 0 \\
g_t(t,x) + a_1(t,x) g_x(t,x) + a_2(t,x) g_{xx}(t,x) + b_2 f(t,x) g(t,x) + e(t,x) g(t,x) + b_3 f(t,x) = 0
$$
where $a_1,a_2,d,e\colon [0;T]\times\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, $c \colon [0;T]\to\mathbb R$ and $b_1,b_2,b_3 \in \mathbb R$.

Is there a theorem in the literature which I could use to prove existence (and if possible, uniqueness) of such a solution under appropriate assumptions? Thank you!